# How can I determine if column of a stored procedure result can be null

Tags: c#, sql, code-generation

I'm writing a code generator and am getting stuck on determining the nullable status of a stored procedure result set Column. I can query the DataType just fine but neither the datareader object nor a data table column contain the correct nullable value of my column.

```
        public List<DataColumn> GetColumnInfoFromStoredProcResult(string schema, string storedProcName)
    {
        //build sql text
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("SET FMTONLY OFF; SET FMTONLY ON; \n");//this is how EF4.1 did so I copied..not sure why the repeat

        sb.Append(String.Format("exec {0}.{1} ", schema, storedProcName));

        var prms = GetStoredProcedureParameters(schema: schema, sprocName: storedProcName);
        var count = 1;
        foreach (var param in prms)
        {
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}=null", param.Name));
            if (count < prms.Count)
            {
                sb.Append(", ");
            }
            count++;
        }

        sb.Append("\n SET FMTONLY OFF; SET FMTONLY OFF;");

        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        //var list = new List<DataColumn>();

        using (var sqlConnection = this.SqlConnection)
        {
            using (var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sb.ToString(), sqlConnection))
            {
                if (sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open) sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
                sqlConnection.Close();
                sqlAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }

            //using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
            //{

            //    sqlCommand.CommandText = sb.ToString();
            //    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            //    sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
            //    if (sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open) sqlConnection.Open();

            //    var dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
            //    var whateva = dr.GetSchemaTable();

            //    foreach (DataColumn col in whateva.Columns)
            //    {
            //        list.Add(col);
            //    }
            //}
        }

        var list = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();

        return list;
    }
```

I'm trying to end up with something similar to the the Entities Framework creation of a complex type from a stored procedure. Can I hijack that functionality?

On this example the Id column.. tblJobId (not my naming convention) would never be null.. But I selected null as ImNull and it has all the same properties so how does EF determine if the corresponding C# data type should be nullable or not?

Has anybody done this..

Ideas are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: *I'm trying to end up with something similar to the the Entities Framework creation of a complex type from a stored procedure. Can I hijack that functionality?* - Yeah, use the entity framework.

Comment: This code generator creates stored procedure calls for the Enterprise Data Access Block. I used Linq to EDMX to code generate middle tier and auto import sprocs for Entities. Good stuff but I only want the part that determines if the column can be null or not so I can create the property and object from the sproc result. EF turned out to be too slow for my table count and I'm tired of waiting for the 'wizard' to update the entire edmx even when I only updated one sproc.

Comment: You can rely on standard SMO calls for this. I've used `StoredProcedureParameter.DefaultValue` parameter with some success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret was to use Schema Only and fill a dataset not datatable. Now the AllowDbNull property on the datacolumn properly displays the nullable status of the return value.

This was it...

```
 public List<DataColumn> GetColumnInfoFromStoredProcResult(string schema, string storedProcName)
    {
        //build sql text
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("SET FMTONLY OFF; SET FMTONLY ON; \n");//this is how EF4.1 did so I copied..not sure why the repeat

        sb.Append(String.Format("exec {0}.{1} ", schema, storedProcName));

        var prms = GetStoredProcedureParameters(schema: schema, sprocName: storedProcName);
        var count = 1;
        foreach (var param in prms)
        {
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}=null", param.Name));
            if (count < prms.Count)
            {
                sb.Append(", ");
            }
            count++;
        }

        sb.Append("\n SET FMTONLY OFF; SET FMTONLY OFF;");

        var ds = new DataSet();
        using (var sqlConnection = this.SqlConnection)
        {
            using (var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sb.ToString(), sqlConnection))
            {
                if (sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open) sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
                sqlConnection.Close();
                sqlAdapter.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "MyTable");
            }
        }

        var list = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();

        return list;
    }

    public List<SqlParamInfo> GetStoredProcedureParameters(string schema, string sprocName)
    {
        var sqlText = String.Format(
            @"SELECT
                [Name] = N'@RETURN_VALUE',
                [ID] = 0,
                [Direction] = 6,
                [UserType] = NULL,
                [SystemType] = N'int',
                [Size] = 4,
                [Precision] = 10,
                [Scale] = 0
            WHERE
                OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'{0}.{1}'), 'IsProcedure') = 1
            UNION
            SELECT
                [Name] = CASE WHEN p.name <> '' THEN p.name ELSE '@RETURN_VALUE' END,
                [ID] = p.parameter_id,
                [Direction] = CASE WHEN p.is_output = 0 THEN 1 WHEN p.parameter_id > 0 AND p.is_output = 1 THEN 3 ELSE 6 END,
                [UserType] = CASE WHEN ut.is_assembly_type = 1 THEN SCHEMA_NAME(ut.schema_id) + '.' + ut.name ELSE NULL END,
                [SystemType] = CASE WHEN ut.is_assembly_type = 0 AND ut.user_type_id = ut.system_type_id THEN ut.name WHEN ut.is_user_defined = 1 OR ut.is_assembly_type = 0 THEN st.name WHEN ut.is_table_type =1 Then 'STRUCTURED' ELSE 'UDT' END,
                [Size] = CONVERT(int, CASE WHEN st.name IN (N'text', N'ntext', N'image') AND p.max_length = 16 THEN -1 WHEN st.name IN (N'nchar', N'nvarchar', N'sysname') AND p.max_length >= 0 THEN p.max_length/2 ELSE p.max_length END),
                [Precision] = p.precision,
                [Scale] = p.scale
            FROM
                sys.all_parameters p
                INNER JOIN sys.types ut ON p.user_type_id = ut.user_type_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types st ON ut.system_type_id = st.user_type_id AND ut.system_type_id = st.system_type_id
            WHERE
                object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'{0}.{1}') 
            ORDER BY 2", schema, sprocName);


        using (var sqlConnection = this.SqlConnection)
        {
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
            {
                if (sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open) sqlConnection.Open();

                sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlText;

                var dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                var result = new List<SqlParamInfo>();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]) != "@RETURN_VALUE")
                    {
                        result.Add(new SqlParamInfo(dr));
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I'm doing a similar project and this helped immensely! Thank you!

Comment: Here is a link to one version of the code gen ... http://enterprisecodegen.azurewebsites.net/   and I have since moved to one project use T4 templates, since my code gen never lasted beyond one project at at time. www.achadwick.com. Hit me up for the source code if you want it. The dll can be found here https://github.com/TheDev6/Koozy/tree/master/CodeGeneration/CodeGen . Also http://brewdawg.github.io/Tiraggo.EF/ totally unpacked the edmx (which I think is going away in EF7?), which is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, that every column which comes from SP can be null - this is a valid assumption because stored procedure - its a kind of *data abstraction layer* and thus its code can change but still produce valid results.

If column was non-nullable yesterday it means nothing for today. So - all the columns which come from SP resultsets are nullable by design.

**Update.**

Assuming that table t1 has column `Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY`

Your stored proc looks like this:

```
CREATE PROC p1
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT Id FROM t1
END
```

So it will never return an Id = NULL, but this is the SP - an abstraction of data, so - tomorrow i'll modify it like this:

```
CREATE PROC p1
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT Id FROM t1
  UNION
  SELECT NULL
END
```

So, now it returns NULL - think about this. The difference in understanding of **data abstraction**

Comment: Thanks.. but what about the case of a primary key, is identity, not null column? I know if it is selected as part of any query it will never be null and I can map it to a non nullable type. My database is normalized and related and I expect it to break if I change it without refactoring dependent code.

Comment: You understand the problem but I don't want C# to statically accept any result set from a sql proc when my goal is to implicitly define the object. If the proc changes, I MUST revisit my C# mapping to obj, no different then if I  select an additional column. Data Abstraction seems more like an architectural decision about how to connect a sql result to a C# object rather than my preferred goal of implicitly matching the result to a C# type which is the point of my question. I want Case 1 = "int Id {get;set;}" Case2="int? Id{get;set;"  Maybe my objective is more like Object Relational Mapping.